# Getting a CGIImageRef from an NSImage in Cocoa on Mac OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, nsimage

I need to get a CGIImageRef from an NSImage. Is there an easy way to do this in Cocoa for Mac OS X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you need to target Mac OS X 10.5 or any other previous release, use the following snippet instead. If you don’t, then NSD’s answer is the right way to go.

```
CGImageRef CGImageCreateWithNSImage(NSImage *image) {
    NSSize imageSize = [image size];

    CGContextRef bitmapContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imageSize.width, imageSize.height, 8, 0, [[NSColorSpace genericRGBColorSpace] CGColorSpace], kCGBitmapByteOrder32Host|kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    [NSGraphicsContext saveGraphicsState];
    [NSGraphicsContext setCurrentContext:[NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:bitmapContext flipped:NO]];
    [image drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
    [NSGraphicsContext restoreGraphicsState];

    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmapContext);
    CGContextRelease(bitmapContext);
    return cgImage;
}
```

If your image comes from a file you may be better off using an [image source](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGImageSource/Reference/reference.html) to load the data directly into a CGImageRef.

Comment: I did something similar to this to use the data from the bitmapContext. An important gotcha: if you want to use the data from the context, you need to call flushGraphics on the NSGraphicsContext. Without this it worked fine in debug mode but segfaulted in release mode.

Answer (score 15):

Pretty hard to miss:

[-[NSImage CGImageForProposedRect:context:hints:]](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000344-SW109)